# Typescript fail because imports in d.ts files are missing `import type`

Tags: typescript

users of [Inquirer reported issues with the library `d.ts` files](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/issues/1253) and I have a hard time figuring it out.

They're running into this error: `error TS2846: A declaration file cannot be imported without 'import type'`; and here's the exact error trace:

```
(1) lukeocodes~/Projects/Deepgram/deepgram-cli(lo/prep-for-beta-release|✚2) % npm run build 

> @deepgram/cli@0.1.0 build
> shx rm -rf dist && tsc -b

node_modules/@inquirer/core/dist/cjs/types/index.d.cts:6:27 - error TS2846: A declaration file cannot be imported without 'import type'. Did you mean to import an implementation file './lib/prefix' instead?

6 export { usePrefix } from './lib/prefix.d.cts';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@inquirer/core/dist/cjs/types/index.d.cts:7:15 - error TS2846: A declaration file cannot be imported without 'import type'. Did you mean to import an implementation file './lib/key' instead?

7 export * from './lib/key.d.cts';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@inquirer/core/dist/cjs/types/index.d.cts:8:15 - error TS2846: A declaration file cannot be imported without 'import type'. Did you mean to import an implementation file './lib/Paginator' instead?

8 export * from './lib/Paginator.d.cts';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@inquirer/core/dist/cjs/types/index.d.cts:9:15 - error TS2846: A declaration file cannot be imported without 'import type'. Did you mean to import an implementation file './lib/Separator' instead?

9 export * from './lib/Separator.d.cts';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Found 4 errors.
```

I would assume this was coming from user's tsconfig; but no options stood out. And those files are generated by typescript (though I manually rename them to `d.cts` after the build otherwise it cause an issue with an older Typescript version). Makes me wonder if in cjs mode (`d.cts`) some different rules are enforced by typescript?

Also, is there a way to force the typescript compiler to generates d.ts with the `import type` syntax? This might just make it easier to anyone integrating with the library.

Comment: Did you manually rename the generated .d.ts files to .d.cts after the build?

Comment: @VictorL. yes, a file rename. By default typescript generates them as `d.mts` due to how the repo is setup. And that will cause older version of Typescript to masquerade as ESM (and it works fine in v18).

Comment: You can try using the --declarationDir flag in your TypeScript compiler options to specify a different output directory for the .d.mts files. This way, you can keep them separate from the .d.cts files and avoid any conflicts or confusion.

Comment: @VictorL. Thanks for jumping on trying to help! I don't think that's related to the problem, you can see the `./dist` generated by the package here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@inquirer/prompts?activeTab=code - you'll see both format are separated with their own types. But let me know if I misunderstood your meaning

Comment: This error seems to be related to how TypeScript resolves the module imports, not how they are generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As might be guessed, this was an error coming from the project and not a misconfiguration.

Imports from `.d.ts` files are either disallowed (in v4), or must be prefixed by `type` (ex `import type Foo from 'file.d.ts'`.)

But most of the time, you never want to import from a `.d.ts` file. Type definition files imports should be the `.js` or `.mjs` source files; even if the path generated won't exist. Typescript knows how to handle that.

So the problem is the import statement inside the root `.d.ts` files should not import from the other `.d.ts` files; it should import from their `.js` file.